# Group homomorphism of elliptic curve which is not an isogeny

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, isogeny

An isogeny $\phi: (E,O)\to (E',O')$ between elliptic curves $E$ and $E'$ is a morphism that satisfies $\phi(O)=O'$.

It is known that $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

Could you provide an example of a group homomorphism between elliptic curves that is not an isogeny?

Thank you in advance for your example.

Comment: For example, complex conjugation $(x,y)\mapsto(\overline{x},\overline{y})$ on $y^2=x^3+1$ is not an isogeny.

Comment: If you take two elliptic curves over a finite field (or possibly over two different finite fields) then you can find plenty of examples of homomorphisms of groups unrelated to isogenies. True, this is only between the groups of rational points, but you didn't specify that. Similarly, it should be possible to  find suitable elliptic curves with no isogenies, but isomorphic (over $\Bbb{Q}$) torsion groups as well as equal ranks.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde. What is an example over rational number field $\Bbb{Q}$ ?